# Outlook - Auto-Forward Email with original attachment

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've seen this question posted several times but after looking extensively, I have not found a successful answer.

I'm trying to create a script for Outlook that auto-forwards an email with an attachment back to the sender, with an updated message, that includes the original attachment. It's all working EXCEPT no matter what I do I cannot forward the attachment. If I just use .Forward, the attachment is not included. If I try to use the .Attachment property, it breaks the script.

CODE:

```
Sub ForwardEmail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    With Item.Forward
        .Attachments.Add Item.Attachment
        .Subject = ("APPROVED - ") & Item.Subject
        .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
        .Body = "Your timesheet has been approved." & vbCrLf & Item.Body
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Attachment from the original email or attach the original email to new email?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Outlook (and other email engines like Gmail, Yahoo) has been designed in this way:

1. When a mail is replied, the receiver do not need same attachments as the receiver already has them in their outbox (unless deleted). It saves storage space on server and network bandwidth too.
2. When a mail is forwarded, it is expected that forward is generally to at least a new user and hence all the content remain as is (i.e. attachments aren't removed)

Hence, please use this code. It follows the Rule#2 mentioned above i.e. whenever you forward an email, the attachment will be automatically attached.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(item As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oMail As MailItem    

  On Error GoTo Release

  If item.Class = olMail Then
     Set oMail = item.Forward
     oMail.Subject = ("APPROVED - ") & Item.Subject
     oMail.HTMLBody = "Your timesheet has been approved." & vbCrLf &  oMail.HTMLBody
     oMail.Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress

     oMail.Save
     oMail.Send
  End If
 Release:
  Set oMail = Nothing
  Set oExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The idea is that the email will always be sent back to the original sender and the attachment must be included. This code doesn't seem to address that. I need to use the line 'oMail.Recipients.Add oMail.SenderEmailAddress'. Can you help with that?

Comment: @user3654518: Please use the updated code and try to understand that Email Forward contain attachments by default. So, idea is to forward the email and change the subject, body and list of recipient(s).